# How to get an entire line in the loop variable of the for command

Tags: bash, shell

When I launch a beta command I've got this result :

```
dda6e95c-ecd1-4c22-a8df-f118af6aff02 Mount to DZ70cd on /dev/vda
f01e331e-0394-423f-b8ea-150f6b88029e Mount to DZ74cd on /dev/vdc
9f0d31ec-caa2-4e88-9cbd-4c82ebda5be3 Mount to DZe64c on /dev/vdc
2f3da174-1f9e-40e7-8869-563d90b103f4 Mount to DZ0d76 on /dev/vdc
```

I would like to apply a data-processing on each line received with a bash loop for as :

```
 for i in `beta-command` ; do echo $i  ; done ;
```

and I've got the resilt like this  :

```
dda6e95c-ecd1-4c22-a8df-f118af6aff02
Mount
to
DZ70cd
on
/dev/vda
f01e331e-0394-423f-b8ea-150f6b88029e
Mount
to
DZ74cd
on
/dev/vdc
```

How to ask the loop to consider the line and not the term ?

Thank

Comment: Good reading: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/117549

Comment: HI Jeff good acknowledge of the post as the loop while concerned that didn 't appear in my own search

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set the [Internal Field Separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_field_separator) (`IFS`) to newline:

```
IFS=$'\n'; for i in $(beta-command) ; do echo $i; done
```

---

Or use a `while` loop:

```
while IFS= read -r i; do
  echo $i
done < <(beta-command)
```

---

or use `xargs`:

```
beta-command | xargs -I{} echo {}
```

---

or use `awk` if your task is about manipulating text:

```
beta-command | awk '{print}'
```

---

Regarding the pros (?) and **cons** of using loops to process each line of command output or a file, you might [read this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/117549) *(thanks @Jeff Schaller)*.